# Ruby gem; type of process that loaded it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am writing a gem and I have it referenced in the Gemfile.  Regardless of whether I call a rake task or start up Webbrick, that gem gets loaded.

I want to detect whether it was loaded from a Rake task or from the web server.

How can my gem detect what type of process loaded the gem?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at $0 and see what "main" file loaded it and figure it out from that. Rake's main file is called "rake", your webserver shouldn't start from the same file.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Looks like I actually wanted to be looking at the value of $0 .  Thanks.